# Rails sqlserver schema dump not generating primary key for non identity pk's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2008

given these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ASTROLOGY_SIGN](
  [SIGN_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ASTROLOGY_SIGN] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACTIVITY_MASTER](
  [ACTIVITY_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ACTIVITY_MASTER] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
```

rails generates the following two entries in schema.rb

```
create_table "ASTROLOGY_SIGN", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
create_table "ACTIVITY_MASTER", :primary_key => "ACTIVITY_ID", :force => true do |t|
```

Trying to use the schema to move from sqlserver to postgres but this is giving me issues.  There are a lot of tables and would rather not have to edit by hand.

Answer (score 1):

friend may this help you...
There are some relations for your tables and their columns in SQLServer as join relations. look:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
```

with all this information, you can program a little program to convert those.
I meant you can access to this information about your tables and columns and then by replacing them in string, the string that is query in **postgres** .look:

```
for(every table in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES )
{
    string postgres_query = "create_table " + TABLE_NAME + ", :id => false, :force => true do |t|"
    exec(postgres_query)
}
```

and then execute it for every table into datacenter(postgres) . of course you have to optimize it to what you exactly want.You know this is not right code